# C++ best way to return minimum of many recursive calls

Tags: c++, recursion, dynamic-programming, minimum

I am trying to solve a dynamic programming question with recursive calls. `dp[i][j]` should be equal to minimum of`dp[i-1][j], dp[i-1][j-1], dp[i-1][j+1]`. But i can only use the c++ minimum function for 2 variables, or a vector. I don't wanna push my results to a vector, so I am asking whats the best way I can solve this problem. Here is the code

```cpp
int dpF(vector<vector<int>>& A, vector<vector<int>>dp,int i,int j)
    {
        if(i<0||i>=A.size()||j<0||j>A.size())
            return 0;
        if(dp[i][j]!=-1)
        {
            return dp[i][j];
        }

        dp[i][j]=A[i][j]+Math.min(dpF(A,dp,i-1,j-1),dpF(A,dp,i-1,j),dpF(A,dp,i-1,j+1)); //Here is the problem, I am trying to find an elegant way to return the minimum of these 3 values.
        return dp[i][j];
    }
```

Comment: Is there any issue with simply nesting `min(min(a,b),min(c,d))`?

Answer (score 4):

[`std::min`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) provides an overload that accepts a `std::initializer_list`. You can do:

```
std::min({dpF(A,dp,i-1,j-1), dpF(A,dp,i-1,j), dpF(A,dp,i-1,j+1)})
```

Comment: Thank you this is a good answer, but I think visual studio 2012 compiler doesn't support initializer_list, is there another way?

Comment: You could write your own function that accepts 3 arguments. Or use a C-style array and `std::min_element`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do  min(dpF(A,dp,i-1,j-1),min(dpF(A,dp,i-1,j),dpF(A,dp,i-1,j+1));

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. To improve this answer, would it be possible for you to edit it to include a brief description of your solution, and use `code formatting` for your code snippets?